# Access Path Name for Transporter Speed Limit

Tags: anylogic

I want to customize the "Speed limit for transporters" option in the Path object. I do call a global function which gives the speedlimit based on the Path Name (Lookup-Table).
Unfortunately

> this.name()

does not return the name of the Path. Any idea how to access the individual Paths name from inside this function?

[image: CodeExample]

Best,
Felipe

Answer (score 0):

There is no "handle" to make this work. `this` does not refer to your `Path` element here.

You can find out by clicking inside the code box. If there is no small "light bulb" with some help text, you have no "handle" for such special functionality. [I wrote a full blog post about this](https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling).

With this setup, you can only get the name by calling the object directly as `path.getName()`.